# sed search replace pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have files with below text (and more).

```
import (
    "http"
    "web"
)
```

I want to replace all `"web"` with `"pkg/web"` (in all files). so the outcome needs to

```
 import (
        "http"
        "pkg/web"
    )
```

I try `sed` like

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/"web"/c\"pkg/web"'
```

which gives error.

```
sed: 1: "test" invalid command code .
```

what is the correct way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you're using `/` as regex delimiter but also using `/` in your replacement string.

Good news is that `sed` allows different regex delimiters.

This sed with a different regex delimiter should work:

```
sed -i.bak 's~^\( *\)"web" *$~\1"pkg/web"~g'
```

**UPDATE:** To preserve whitespace on LHS of searched string:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0  sed -i '' 's~^\([[:space:]]*\)"web"[[:space:]]*$~\1"pkg/web"~g'
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't follow the pattern, but for safety, can we enforce, the pattern to match "web" and replacement text "pkg/web" is restricted to full line. means there is no other content in that line. may be it is like that already, please confirm.

Comment: Yes see my edited answer now. It will only replace `"web"` if there is not other content on the line except spaces on either side.

Comment: it didn't work. it created a file test.bak, with the same content!

Comment: `test.bak` is same content as the original but test file will have changed content.

Comment: no. both are same. Also, I don't want to create a bkp file, as there are lot of files and don't want to delete all later

Comment: this is the command I used.  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's~^\( *\)"web" *$~\1"pkg/web"~g'

Comment: correct command is: **`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's~^\( *\)"web" *$~\1"pkg/web"~g'`**

Comment: parentheses needs to be escaped in regular sed command and I have moved `.bak` creation.

Comment: which gives familiar error. sed: 1: "./test": invalid command code .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39990/discussion-between-bsr-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0):

> find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0  sed -i -e 's@"web"@"pkg/web"@g'

This works fine for me.